# Meaning of this expression for Vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

To eliminate duplication, these directions may be normalized, e.g. $e^T d = 1$. Here $d$ is a direction but what is $e$. Is it just a vector full of ones?

Comment: Very often $e$ is used for a vector of all ones, so that you write $e^Td=1$ as a shorthand for $\mathrm{sum}(d)=1$, although it wouldn't hurt to include some more context.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek It is for finding the extreme directions of a polyhedron. To eliminate duplication, these directions may be normalized.